# Mix of Procedural and Manual level design / creation in UE4

Tags: procedural-generation, unreal-4, level-design

I'm trying to design a maze using a mix of procedural and manual generation. I have the maze already generated and would like to place other objects in the maze manually in the editor. The issue is the maze object is created on BeginPlay and so I'm unable to view it in the Editor itself while dragging the object to the Outliner. Any suggestions?

I'm thinking of doing something in the Construction Script or the object Constructor but not not sure if that would be the way to go.

I'm still getting familiar with the Engine code base and only have a little experience in Maya or Blender since I'm a programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to run code from within the editor that creates the actors that represent your maze and saves them in the level you have open. Then you can position the maze however you want and place objects within it. Most likely you will do this through an editor plugin.

You'll need to look up how to create an editor module either inside a plugin or alongside your game module. After that creating a property inspector for the maze generation properties and a button to create the actors in the current editor world.

When creating a new plugin from within the UE4 editor there is a dropdown for choosing what sample you want to start with as well. Exploring a few of those options might give you some clues on your way forward.

[UE4 Editor Extention Live Training](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zg_VstBxDi8) This one is a bit out of date personally but it's great for performing helper tasks when in the editor

There are a ton of resources on UE4 editor extensions. I don't think that I could fit an entire tutorial into an answer. But hopefully it puts you onto the right track.

Comment: oh perfect! That sure would help! I was actually looking at the Blutility tool. That seemed to be pretty helpful.

Comment: @RJSkywalker it sounds as if this answer solved your problem - if so, you should [mark it as the accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/228147)